# How to remove repetition of the content of file by column?

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, perl, sort

I have a file containing the following content:

```
WP_021815421.1  OG5_132922  deth|YP_182312  3   -07 42.35   81.7
WP_021815427.1  OG5_128110  rbal|NP_868155  1   -55 50.72   53.2
WP_012456834.1  NO_GROUP    bsui|NP_700181  8   -53 48.18   62
WP_084606289.1  OG5_132922  aful|NP_069703  5   -28 57.00   92.6
WP_084606284.1  OG5_153487  bpse|YP_331974.1    6   -78 48.87   91.4
```

I want to remove the repitition line on the base of second coloumn `(OG number)`. the output should not contain third row which contain the same `OG number`.

I am using `sort -u` and `sort -k 2 -u`  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your expected output?

Comment: Don't you mean that you want to omit the *fourth* row, where `OG5_132922` matches the first row?

Comment: Which row are you keeping when more rows share the same value for their second column? It looks like you want to keep the first row from the top of the file. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the sort field to the second column (and not from the second column to the end of the line), you have to specify the end position:

```
$ sort -uk2,2  file
WP_012456834.1  NO_GROUP    bsui|NP_700181  8   -53 48.18   62
WP_021815427.1  OG5_128110  rbal|NP_868155  1   -55 50.72   53.2
WP_021815421.1  OG5_132922  deth|YP_182312  3   -07 42.35   81.7
WP_084606284.1  OG5_153487  bpse|YP_331974.1    6   -78 48.87   91.4
```

Comment: Be careful, this solution will also sort alphabetically by the second column.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '!seen[$2]++' file
```

This will print only lines which are unique in the second column. Output:

```
WP_021815421.1  OG5_132922  deth|YP_182312  3   -07 42.35   81.7                                                                                                                                                                          
WP_021815427.1  OG5_128110  rbal|NP_868155  1   -55 50.72   53.2                                                                                                                                                                             
WP_012456834.1  NO_GROUP    bsui|NP_700181  8   -53 48.18   62                                                                                                                                                                               
WP_084606284.1  OG5_153487  bpse|YP_331974.1    6   -78 48.87   91.4
```